# Start glances with a few switches

Tags: gnome-terminal, startup-applications, monitoring, system-monitor, htop

I've got the gnome-terminal set to open on login, using the following command: `gnome-terminal -- glances`. I'd like to use these commands that work when glances is running, at launch: `/ 0 U F`. I'm not finding the answer in the manual. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by " I'd like to use these commands that work when glances is running, at launch: / 0 U F."

Comment: When the terminal launches and runs glances with no flags, I then hit those keys for those options, 0) Show CPU as cumulative, /) show process name first, U) show cumulative network stats, F) show free space on filesystems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are in-process switches, accessible by typing `h` within. I can't find a way to list cumulative network meter from the command line. However, I found the following command gives all the other functionality...

`$ glances -0 -b --fs-free-space --process-short-name`

`-0` lists CPU by overall work, not only for the core(s) the process uses
`-b` shows Byte-form data instead of bits
`--fs-free-space` shows free space on volumes, switching from filled space
`--process-short-name` takes a lot of the path out and shows the command name firsst

Glances is a pretty neat app. I launch it on login, now with the above command.

[image]

[image]